# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

i have 2 test files, ScenarioAuth and ScenarioBugReport

Scenario Auth:

```
public class ScenarioauthTest {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private Map<String, Object> vars;
  JavascriptExecutor js;
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  }
  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
  }

  public void testauth() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:3000/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("startPageAuth")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("authFormEmail")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("authFormEmail")).sendKeys(vars.get("mail").toString());
    driver.findElement(By.id("authFormAuth")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("authSubmitFormPassword")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("authSubmitFormPassword")).sendKeys(vars.get("password").toString());
    driver.findElement(By.id("authSubmitFormAuth")).click();
  }
  @Test
  public void scenarioauth() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    vars.put("mail", "myMail");
    vars.put("password", "12345");
    testauth();
  }
}
```

i need import public void `testAuth()` method to ScenarioBugReport

i tried like this in ScenarioBugReport in test column:

```
@Test
    public void scenariogroupChatAdminRole() {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        vars.put("mail", "test001@mail.ru");
        vars.put("password", "12345");
        ScenarioauthTest auth = new ScenarioauthTest();
        auth.testauth();
        testbugReport();
    }
```

but get `Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null`